# Calculus and integration proof

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Hi I recently learned the mean value theorem send i noticed that the mean value theorem for derivatives stated that c is a set of (a,b) in the open interval however for the mean value theorem of definite integrals c is a set of [a,b]
I find this quite confusing how can the average value of a function be at the end points?
Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, what if the function in question was, say, a constant function?

Comment: Ah I see but for the mean value theorem of derivatives the function may not be differentiable at its end points such as y=$\sqrt{x}$